# iOS URLSession Initiate DownloadTask in Background

Tags: ios, swift, networking, download, nsurlsession

I am trying to build a sequential download manager where the user can initiate up to 1000 download tasks at once but only 2 will actually download and the rest will be put on hold, until one of the two finishes so that another one of the 998 can start.

Because there is no way to add a `downloadTask` then have that task wait for others to complete then automatically start, I have built a download queue myself and will only create new `downloadTask` when the old one completes.

I have read the documentations and am well aware of the mechanism of iOS's handling of background download event, and what methods I need to implement in order to handle them correctly. However, I am unable to find anything on whether it is safe and reliable to start a new `downloadTask` when the old one completes IN BACKGROUND.

**The Main Question:**

When iOS relaunches my app in background to inform me that my download tasks are finished, can I  ***reliably*** create a new `downloadTask` and add it to the current session? If so, when that task finishes as well, will the system relaunch my app AGAIN to tell me it's finished? If so, then I can create an infinite loop of adding new tasks when the old `backgroundTask` finish.

***Code Example***

Would the following code reliable to get the entire download queue downloaded(say, 1000 items) if I download ONLY one item at a time and meanwhile the app stays entirely in background?

```
extension MyClass: URLSessionDelegate {
  func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {

    // This is called when background tasks are done
    // Let's add a new background tasks WHILE app has just been 
    // relaunched IN BACKGROUND

    if let nextURL = myURLQueue.removeFirst() {
        session.downloadTask(with: URLRequest(url: nextURL))
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let completionHandler = appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler {
        appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = nil

        completionHandler()
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Rather than try to describe the situation we'd rather see the smallest piece of code that demonstrates the problem. With a description only we have to give general comments, with code we can give very concise comments and explain specifically how to do something.

Comment: It's been edited and added a code sample @theTinMan

Comment: It's not necessary to tell us you made a change. We can see what changed, and when, because SO maintains revision tracking for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `URLSessionDownloadTask`, but never starting it with [`resume()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/1411121-resume).

---

FWIW, even if you fix the above, you should recognize that requests that are submitted while the app is running in background mode will always be submitted in discretionary mode. As [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411552-isdiscretionary) for `isDiscretionary` say:

> For transfers started while your app is in the background, the system always starts transfers at its discretion—in other words, the system assumes this property is true and ignores any value you specified.

Also, recognize that having the system fire up your app every time a request is done in order to submit the next request is both inefficient (because your app will constantly fire up and go back into background) and slow (because concurrent requests reduce latency effects). It’s generally better to just submit all of the requests up front, while the app is active, and let the background session manage how many it will allow to run concurrently.

Comment: That's right. Thanks for pointing that out. I am aware of the `isDiscretionary` mode and since there's nothing we can do, I am not taking it into consideration. So from what you are saying(and the docs seems to be suggesting this too): it is ok to start a new task in background and the system will accept it(although may not start it) and will report its success or failure. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you can start requests while the app is running in background.